# Delphi Firemonkey does not display fonts correctly

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I'm building cross-platform desktop app with additional font (Abilene). On startup I check is the font installed and if it is not, I install it and use it. For Mac everything seems to be fine, but Windows version (and the IDE!!) does not display the font correctly. Here is the font installation procedure:

```
procedure InstallFont;
const
  REG_NT = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts';

var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  res: Boolean;
  installName,FileName: UnicodeString;

begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_ALL_ACCESS);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    res := Reg.OpenKey(REG_NT, False);
    if not Res then Exit;

    installName := 'Abilene Regular (TrueType)';
    FileName:=ExtractFilePath(ParamCount(0)+'\Abilene.ttf';
    Reg.WriteString(installName, FileName);
    Reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;

  AddFontResourceW(PWideChar(FileName));
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE,0,0);
end;
```

After installing the font it is displayed as shortcut in the Control panel, but all other programs can use it. Even Delphi can, but with VCL, not FMX applications (see attached pictures).  I've attached pictures from the IDE. In the runtime it's the same.

Is there anything that must be done additionally for the font installation especially for FMX apps? Or this is just a bug which must be reported to Embarcaderro QC?

[image: FMX IDE]

[image: VCL IDE]

Edit: Adding some details: If I install the font by downloading it, clicking with the right mouse button and choose 'Install' then everything is OK. If I install it by my proc then the font is visible and usable for the whole world except the Delphi FMX. Delphi VCL can use it also. To test this I install ed the font with my proc in my %APPDATA% folder. Word, Excel, Delphi VCL can use it. Delphi FMX cannot.

Edit2: Added SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE,0,0). No change.

Edit3: In the Font dialog the font is displayed correctly (image 3)
[image]

Comment: This seems all wrong to me. You are going to force your app to show the UAC dialog to the users every time it runs, just so that it can do a one time only font install? Put the font install into your installer. As for the FMX specific issue, I think that's independent of the installation right? Even if you install it manually, outside of your program, you are saying that FMX won't display it correctly? Or is the problem only when you install the font from your program?

Comment: I first check is the font installed, i.e. if in the registry exists a key Abilene Regular (TrueType) the procedure is just skipped.

Comment: And if I install the font from the wizard and never check for it the user can uninstall it from the Control panel

Comment: All the same, you will be forcing the UAC dialog onto your users every time your program is run. You didn't answer any of the questions that I asked.

Comment: If I install the font by downloading it, clicking with the right mouse button and choose 'Install' then everything is OK. If I install it by my proc then the font is visible and usable for the whole world except the Delphi FMX. Delphi VCL can use it also. To test this I install ed the font with my proc in my %APPDATA% folder. Word, Excel, Delphi VCL can use it. Delphi FMX cannot.

Comment: Please put the details in the question not in comments. The simple answer is that you solve all your problems by installing the font properly in your program's installer.

Comment: >The simple answer is that you solve all your problems by installing the font properly in your program's installer. --- Don't agree. If I don't check is the font installed I cannot be sure is the font present when the program is launched.

Comment: You are completely ignoring the issue of UAC. Why do you want to present UAC dialogs to the user every time she starts your program?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I don't think I can help you

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that the proper way to install fonts is through your installer. I'm going to be very angry at the app that insists on reinstalling a font I don't want (and that I've uninstalled) from my system, and I'm certainly going to let the company or programmer that provided it know about it (after I've removed the app). The fonts on the machine belong to the user, and you're wrong in trying to force it down their throat.

Comment: @KenWhite But I really don't want to install font just for this program. My first attempt was just to use AddFontResourceW and ReleaseFontResourceW and therefore to use the font w/o installing. This didn't work for FMX, so I wrote installation procedure with font in the program's folder. This did not work also so I asked here is anything wrong with my proc or this is just the next Firemonkey bug. In the deleted answer David gave there was the `SendMessage` command which I forgot to implement, but it didn't help too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I ignore the UAC because I can't avoid it anyway. I write in the registry some user data (registry is insisted by my boss) so the UAC is present.  Yesterday I reported to my boss and now I'm waiting for proposition/decision.

Comment: @KenWhite  And by the way I'm going to be very angry to be blamed why does not my app behave properly if the user has deleted or uninstalled some of the resources needed.

Comment: @LHristov Nobody writes installers into the program. If the user deletes an important component from your program, it's their fault. The user can just do a repair install to fix it. Sounds like you need to get a new boss.

Comment: It's fine if your app doesn't work because the user deleted a resource, because they can just do a repair installation and correct it, and all is good. If you screw with fonts on my machine, I'm going to uninstall and **not** reinstall it, and you're in much worse condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this is some sort of bug, because I've found a workaround: if I first copy the font to %windir%\Fonts folder then everything is OK. Even if I made a subfolder of the \windows\fonts folder and copy the font in it everything is fine also.

Why Firemonkey does not want to display fonts outside that folder I have no idea. And, as I said, this is for Windows only. Mac OS is OK (I use ~/Library/Fonts).

Comment: You realise that your program requires elevation right?

Comment: Yes, it does. Better than to force reinstallation (with elevation too) if the font is missing.

Comment: I see your point. Why have the user go through the UAC dialog once, when you can make them go through it every single time the program executes?

Comment: I see your point too, but I have already had problems with users who delete this and that, so I first check are all resources on place. I'll try to move installation proc to another app and this probably will be good enough.

Comment: I'd say that you are going about this the wrong way. If users delete the fonts you install, on their head be it. As I've said many times, I believe you are getting this wrong. I've nothing more to say though. I think I made my point.